# display twitpic using actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, twitpic

I would like to find out if it is possible to display twitpic with specific hashtag in flash application. I have been searching online but none has actually provide similiar solution. Please give me some source as reference as I have been stuck for quite awhile. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the twitter API to do a query on a hashtag search. Then use the twitter image domain to pull images for the user's screen name that's in the json result in the query.

URL address to pull images:
http://img.tweetimag.es/i/UserName

Twitter API for searching (includes hashtags):
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! The image retrieved is the user profile image. I will be using the twitter API for searching but I would like to retrieve images posted by different various users and display them. Is it possible? Thank you